# Why does the CSS not take effect using Chrome on a Mac?

Tags: html, css

My daughter is in the process of learning HTML/CSS and have been going through the examples in: *Head First HTML and CSS*  One of the first examples instructs the reader to insert the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Starbuzz Coffee </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            body {
                background-color: #d2b48c;
                margin-left: 20%;
                margin-right: 20%;
                border: 2px dotted black;
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Starbuzz Coffee Beverages </h1>

        <h2> House Blend, $1.49 </h2>
        <p> A smooth, mild blend of coffees from Mexico, Bolivia and   Guatemala.</p>

        <h2> Mocha Cafe Latte, $2.35 </h2>
        <p> Espresso, steamed milk and chocolate syrup. </p>

        <h2> Cappuccino, $1.89 </h2>
        <p> A mixture of espresso, steamed milk and foam.</p>

        <h2> Chai Tea, $1.85 </h2>
        <p> A spicy drink made with black tea, spices, milk and honey.           </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML renders just fine, but the CSS appears to have been ignored and does not appear when one asks to see the code underlying the page.  Ideas about what is missing?  It is difficult to make it through a book if stumbling at the gate.

Comment: Ought to work fine. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/fv5ey337/

Comment: Is Chrome on the Mac the only browser it's not working on? Tried clearing the cache?

Comment: I don't know what the key command is on mac but  refresh(ctrl-f5 on Whindows), or open the window in private browser mode to make sure you don't have a caching issue.

Comment: And they didn't advise to just write `padding: 10px;`? Crappy instructions. It works fine for me btw. Chrome on PC.

Comment: I copied your code into a blank HTML doc and ran it in Chrome on my Macbook.  Works fine for me.  Try updating your browser, refreshing, clearing your cache, private browsing mode, making a new file and testing it, etc.  The problem doesn't appear to be in the code.

Comment: @Aibrean it depends on what you are trying to teach.  It makes sense to show the full code first then "hey here is a short hand notation"